# Reusing a variable in other components with state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to reuse the variable `msg` in another component which is presumably scoped to the component it's declared in. The problem is the variable uses state and cannot be declared above the scope to be accessible to both components.

The `App` component that tries to use the component shows this error: `msg is not defined`

What's the best workaround to solve this issue?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <p>state value from component: {msg}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setMsg("changed")}>change state</button>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        {msg && ( // error here
          <p>show this</p>
        )}
      <p>some text</p>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here's a stackblitz for convenience: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g16stb

Thanks for any help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't pass variables to parent or siblings you need to [lift up state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). find a common ancestor to place your state and pass down as props.

your code should look like:

```
const Test = ({ msg,setMsg }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>state value from component: {msg}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setMsg("changed")}>change state</button>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div>
        {msg && (
          <p>show this</p>
        )}
      <p>some text</p>
      <Test  msg={msg} setMsg={setMsg} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

In-order to access `msg` in the App component it is difficult to access in the parent component from the above code, So we need to **`lift up the state`** and place msg in the App component and pass it as a prop to the Test component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
   const Test = ({ msg,setMsg }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <p>state value from component: {msg}</p>
          <button onClick={() => setMsg("changed")}>change state</button>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    const App = () => {
      const [msg, setMsg] = useState(null);
      return (
        <div>
            {msg && (
              <p>show this</p>
            )}
          <p>some text</p>
          <Test  msg={msg} setMsg={setMsg} />
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```